# Create grid with equal spacings R from specific latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, r, latitude-longitude

I would like to create a grid of 8 points with lat lons (2 x 4) each 200m apart using a specific point as the start, e.g., top left of the grid. My starting point is Latitude 51.83985301, Longitude 0.885039037 would be Point 1. Can I do this in R?

```
Point 1 (x,y)    Point 2 (x,y)
Point 3 (x,y)    Point 4 (x,y)
Point 5 (x,y)    Point 6 (x,y)
Point 7 (x,y)    Point 8 (x,y)
```

Comment: The 2x4 stack would resemble a stair-stepped trapezoid in decimal degrees if you made the 200m delta run up the middle along a meridian.  Rectangles don't plot neighborly on a spheroid.

Comment: Would you like to keep your geodetic crs or are you ok with some reprojections?

Comment: If you start at some point on a sphere and go 200m East, then 200m North, then 200m West, then 200m South you don't get back to where you started from. This is why you can't have a grid in an exact number of metres as a regular lat-long grid. For small grids, and 200 metres is pretty small, the usual approach is to project to a flat coordinate system and use that, accepting the fact that your grid points are not precisely 200m apart any more.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I figured that as it's so small they'd be pretty close, if not exactly 200m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide a hands-on example in addition to @Spacedman's answer, although I'm not 100 % sure if my sf piping operations could be reduced a little bit:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# initialize starting point
p_init <- c("lon" = 0.885039037, "lat" = 51.83985301) |> 
  sf::st_point() |> 
  sf::st_geometry()

# define crs
sf::st_crs(p_init) <- "epsg:4326"

# transform from geodetic to projected crs; here: WGS 84 / UTM 31 N
coords <- sf::st_transform(p_init, "epsg:32631") |> 
  sf::st_coordinates()

# define dimensions, create grid
y <- 2
x <- 4

cellsize <- 200

pts <- data.frame("lat" = rep(coords[, 2], x * y) + (seq(0, by = cellsize, length.out = y) |> rep(each = x)),
                  "lon" = seq(coords[, 1], by = cellsize, length.out = x) |> rep(y)) |> 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "epsg:32631")

# inspect result
plot(pts)
plot(sf::st_transform(p_init, "epsg:32631"), col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Modify your initial coordinates in `p_init` and the grid definition in `x`, `y` and `cellsize` according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `sf` package to create spatial data - points, polygons, lines etc - and at `st_transform` to convert lat-long data (which is usually epsg code 4326) to a local planar coordinate system.

For the location you give, which appears to be in SE England, you can use the Ordnance Survey Grid system, which is EPSG code 27700, elsewhere on the planet other grid systems are suitable, usually the UTM zone for your longitude.

Once converted to planar coordinates, you can add/subtract 200m offsets to your origin as needed to create your grid, and if you need to convert back to lat-long you can use `st_project` again.